How to configure databricks-client
I followed the Microsoft documentation to set up databricks connect. But at the end of the process when I do databricks-connect test, it fails with an error
Missing Python executable 'python3', defaulting to * PySpark is installed at C:\Users\deba\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\db_blueprint12.2\lib\site-packages\pyspark

Checking SPARK_HOME
Checking java version
java version "1.8.0_401"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_401-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.401-b10, mixed mode, sharing)
Skipping scala command test on Windows
Testing python command
The system cannot find the path specified.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect/python/install#configure-connection-python
When I execute the pyspark command, I get the same error.
When I am trying conda list pyspark I don't get anything back, What am I missing?
